# WPF binding where value = X

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Hi Just wanna hear if its possible in xaml to bind to a list, where a value has a certain value.
Ex. in the following example, is it possible with Xaml only to only show the items, where Price = 20?

I'm asking because I'm going to Bind a list of object containing another list, where I only wanna show certain item, depending on there values. Therefor I'm trying to avoid a C# solution.

MainWindow.xaml

```
   <Window x:Class="Binding_Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            DataContext = BuildList();
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        List<Product> BuildList()
        {
            var list = new List<Product>();
            var y = 1;
            for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                list.Add(new Product{Name = string.Format("Item {0}",i), Price = y++ * 10 });
                if (y > 3)
                    y = 1;
            }
            return list;
        }
```

Product.cs

```
public class Product
    {
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public int Price { get; set; }

       public override string ToString()
       {
           return string.Format("{0} \t{1}", Name, Price.ToString("C2"));
       }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a CollectionViewSource with an appropriate filter.  In this case the xaml would look like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding}" x:Key="filtered" Filter="CollectionViewSource_Filter" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource filtered}}"/>
</Grid>
```

and the filter event would look like this:

```
private void CollectionViewSource_Filter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((e.Item as Product).Price == 20)
            {
                e.Accepted = true;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Accepted = false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a ValueConverter

If you create a ValueConvert that takes filter value as a parameter you can then make it return only the entries you want.

```
public class FilterConverter : IValueConverter {

  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
     var list=value as List<Product>();
     if (list==null) return Binding.DoNothing;
     var stringPrice=parameter as string;
     int price;
     if (!int.TryParse(stringPrice,out price)) return Binding.DoNothing;
     return list.Where(i=>i.Price==price).ToList();
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        return Binding.DoNothing;
  }

}
```

Then create a static resource for your converter and reference it in the binding

```
<Window x:Class="Binding_Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:c="PUT A REFERENCE TO THE CONVERTER NAMESPACE HERE!!!"
       Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Window.Resources>
    <c:FilterConverter x:Key="filter" />
  </Window.Resources>
  <Grid>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Converter={StaticResource filter},ConverterParameter=20}"/>
  </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Stolen from [here](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/06/12/searching-for-items-in-a-listbox/):

> WPF has built-in support for filtering
>   items in a list.  ICollectionView has
>   a Filter property, which can be set to
>   an instance of Predicate — a
>   delegate which takes a single Object
>   argument and returns a bool.  Each
>   item in the list is passed through
>   that filter to determine if it is
>   filtered in or out.

An example how to use the filter property can be found [here](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/06/12/searching-for-items-in-a-listbox/)

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom DataTemplate in your ListView and use a DataTrigger to determine which items should be shown or not. Something like:

```
<Style x:Key="HideUnlessSomeConditionIsTrue" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SomeProperty}" Value="SomeValue">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Trigger>
</Style>

<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource HideUnlessSomeConditionIsTrue}" ... />
```

Comment: Would this not result in waste of memory? If ex. its a large list containing Images, and we only wanna show a few of them. Then this solution would still load all images into the list, but hide the ones that's not needed. Though for a small scale its a great solution, an only uses Xaml.

Comment: @Gulbaek I don't think WPF loads items that aren't visible. I know this is the case most controls, but I'd double-check to be sure. You can easily test by adding a Loaded event to the image and see if it gets called. Personally I usually prefer to do it with a CollectionViewSource, but I posted this since you asked for an XAML-Only solution.

Answer (score 0):

I support Leom Burke's solution.

An alternative solution (in your case) could be to use an ObjectDataProvider with MethodParameters.

Have a look at the examples section of this page:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.objectdataprovider.methodname.aspx